# Limit home post to 10 without creating pagination?

Tags: wp-query

I'm trying to display the last 10 posts only on the home without wp creating /page/2, /page/3, archives.

I've been testing and it seems if you disable pagination it will just grab everything crashing the server. (Don't do this at home).

```
if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 10 );
    $query->set( 'nopaging' , true );

    }
```

Someone suggested " no_found_rows=true" that doesn't do it either.

Is this just impossible to do? It seems like it will either create the pages or show all, there's no way to "LIMIT" it?

Comment: You'd need to modify your theme to do this, modifying the query changes what's fetched, not how it's displayed

Comment: I want to fetch 10 not fetch all and display 10.

Comment: I'm also starting to think that perhaps what you are looking at is different from what you intend to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a mistake it will retrieve of posts:

```
  $query->set( 'nopaging' , true );
```

What you should do instead is:

```
if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 10 );
    $query->set( 'paged', '1'); // Makes /page/2/, etc links redirect to home
    $query->set( 'no_found_rows', true ); // Avoid counting rows, faster processing.  

    }
```

If your theme is still rendering the navigation buttons you'll have to add some logic to hide them on the pages you disabled pagination, for me it was the home page:

```
if (!is_home()) {
// show pagination buttons
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent the API from generating pagination links, you can use the `found_posts` filter to make WordPress think there are never more than 10 posts returned from the current query.

```
add_filter( 'found_posts', 'wpd_disable_home_pagination', 10, 2 );
function wpd_disable_home_pagination( $found_posts, $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() && $found_posts > 10 ) {
        return 10;
    }
    return $found_posts;
}
```

EDIT-

You could redirect any paginated URL:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpd_redirect_pagination_urls', 10, 2 );
function wpd_redirect_pagination_urls( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_paged() ) {
        wp_redirect( get_post_type_archive_link( 'post' ) );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this become a very expensive query when there are many more than 10 posts?

Comment: it's the same query that would run on a paginated archive. it's not as fast as it could be, but it's not changing the speed of the default query. why not just create a custom query for 10 posts? or remove the pagination code? what problem are you trying to solve exactly?

Comment: @Milo This just hides pagination links /page/2, /page/3 etc pages still exist if typed on the browser. I want to get only first 10.

Comment: I think i'll have to create my own query instead of attempting to modify the main query. I thought this was trivial.

Comment: See edit for redirecting any paginated URL back to root.

Answer (score 0):

The `nopaging` parameter is used to show all posts or use pagination (https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters). Default value is `'false'`: use paging. So it is expected behaviour when you set it to true, the sky comes falling down (if you have a big number of posts that is).

By using only the `posts_per_page` parameter, the query will grab the number of posts you tell it to and that will be that.

Comment: The code above still grabs all, it ignores posts_per_page

Comment: try removing the conditions (`if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )`) I don't know the context of those conditions and cannot check them so for testing purposes better remove them